# Change Pivot Table Columns Filters with changing source data

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have built a macro that connects to SAP, do its thing, gets the response and writes it down on the spreadsheet. The issue is, before the script could do it, I need to have the data by cluster.

For understanding, I have a list of customers with their codes and I have built a master key for each of them, because before I input it to SAP, I need to filter the customers by master key codes that are equal so SAP will accept it. But on the source file I'll have multiples master key codes.

I made a pivot table and put the master key on the columns, so I can see customers code by master key.

With that in hand I filter by master key and I have the specific customer codes for it, and now I can send it to SAP. And repeat for all master keys on the file.
This information will change every time from the sales department, so the master keys will change everytime too.

What I need to do is get all the master keys from the file (done that) and, the place I'm stuck, use it to hide and show one at time inside a loop.
For example (MK stands for Master Key):

```
Customer MK1 MK2 MK3 MK4
   X      1
   Y          1
   Z          1
   A      1
```

So I filter MK1, get customer code for it, run SAP thing, get back to the pivot, filter next existing code, get the customers code, run SAP and do all over again.

```
If Range("A2") <> "" Then

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).FillDown

    FILTRO2 = ActiveCell

    Range("A1").Select

            Do While ActiveCell <> ""

                FILTRO = ActiveCell

                Sheets("Dinâmica").Activate

                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2").PivotFields("Chave")
                    .PivotItems(Split(FILTRO2.Value, ",")).Visible = False
                    .PivotItems(FILTRO).Visible = True
                End With
```

As seen on above code, I'm on a dead end. Isn't working at all.

Comment: @Peh will study this method... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch each single "masterkey" visible by `Pivotitem.Visible`.
Please be aware, that always at least 1 pivotitem has to remain visible.

The resulting visible "customers" can be read from the `PivotField.DataRange`, which represents all visible pivotitems of that pivotfield. You can address that range cell by cell or assign its value to an array.

```
Private Sub FilterMasterkeys()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pfCustomer As PivotField
    Dim pfMasterkey As PivotField
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range ' a cell

    Set pt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dinâmica").PivotTables("Tabela dinâmica2")
    pt.RefreshTable

    Set pfCustomer = pt.RowFields(1)
    Set pfMasterkey = pt.ColumnFields("Chave")

    ' hide all masterkeys except first
    pfMasterkey.PivotItems(1).Visible = True
    For i = 2 To pfMasterkey.PivotItems.Count
        pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i

    ' set each masterkey visible and get corresponig customers
    For i = 1 To pfMasterkey.PivotItems.Count - 1
        pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        Debug.Print "Masterkey " & pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i).Caption & " is used by ",
        For Each c In pfCustomer.DataRange.Cells
            Debug.Print c.Value,
        Next c
        Debug.Print

        pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i + 1).Visible = True
        pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i

    ' get the last one also
    Debug.Print "Masterkey " & pfMasterkey.PivotItems(i).Caption & "is used by ",
    For Each c In pfCustomer.DataRange.Cells
        Debug.Print c.Value,
    Next c
    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

If you need all corresponding customers as array, use this after you have switched the next masterkey visible:

```
Dim arrCustomers() As Variant
arrCustomers = pfCustomer.DataRange.Value
```

Comment: Dude,that was perfect! Thank you so much!